# Having trouble with a Manipulate showing a ContorPlot and the results of NSolve

Tags: manipulate

I am using a manipulate on a ContourPlot and a NSolve, the code is the following

```
BRfunction[MUU_, Mss_, AU_, As_, AUs_] := 
  1.84692*10^8 (((0.000249253 - 0.0893089 Mss^2 + 15 Mss^4) As)/(4 Mss^8) + 
    (0.198094 (-0.0334908 + 10 Mss^2) AUs)/(Mss^4 MUU^2) + (0.392411 AU)/MUU^4)

Manipulate[
  Column[
    ContourPlot[
      BRfunction[MUU, MYy, AU, As, AUs] == 10^-8, 
      {MUU, 1000, 30000}, 
      {MYy, 1000, 30000}, 
      FrameLabel -> {"MUU", "Mss"}, 
      MaxRecursion -> 6],
    NSolve[
      VU1x1^2*(VU1x2^2 + VU2x1^2) == AU && 
      Oss1x1^2*(Oss1x2^2 + Oss2x1^2) == As && 
      VU1x1*Oss1x1*(VU1x2*Oss1x2 + VU2x1*Oss2x1) == AUs && 
      VU1x1 < 1 && VU1x1 > -1 && VU1x2 < 1 && VU1x2 > -1 && 
      VU2x1 < 1 && VU2x1 > -1 &&
      Oss1x1 < 1 && Oss1x1 > -1 && Oss1x2 < 1 && Oss1x2 > -1 && 
      Oss2x1 < 1 && Oss2x1 > -1, 
      {VU1x1, VU1x2, VU2x1, Oss1x1, Oss1x2, Oss2x1}]], 
  {AU, 0, 0.5}, 
  {As, 0, 2}, 
  {AUs, -1, 1}]
```

The problem is that the conditions within NSolve not always have a solution and result in errors. Because of this (I think) something superposed and unreadable appears in the output box as appears below.

[image]

If I run both commands in separate Manipulates the ContourPlot comes out perfectly and the NSolve works as it is supposed to. How can the same be done inside a single manipulate?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the issue? Or better yet, the full code required to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @LukasLang Thank you for your suggestion! I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. It has the form: Manipulate[Column[ ContourPlot[...], NSolve[...]], ... ] . Column should have the form: Column[{content1, content2,..}, options]. NSolve[..] returns replacement rules, but there is nothing to replace.

Comment: @DanielHuber Thank you for pointing out the syntax error (missing brackets). This should solve the problem if I keep using NSolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your equations seem to mostly have no solution or an infinite number of solutions, I think `FindInstance` will work better in your situation than `NSolve`. So you might try

```
BRfunction[MUU_, Mss_, AU_, As_, AUs_] := 
  1.84692*10^8 (((0.000249253 - 0.0893089 Mss^2 + 
    15 Mss^4) As)/(4 Mss^8) + 
    (0.198094 (-0.0334908 + 10 Mss^2) AUs)/(Mss^4 MUU^2) + 
    (0.392411 AU)/MUU^4)

Manipulate[
  Column[
    {ContourPlot[
       BRfunction[MUU, MYy, AU, As, AUs] == 10^-8, {MUU, 1000, 30000}, {MYy, 1000, 30000},
       FrameLabel -> {"MUU", "Mss"},
       MaxRecursion -> 6,
       ImageSize -> Medium],
     FindInstance[
       VU1x1^2*(VU1x2^2 + VU2x1^2) == AU &&
       Oss1x1^2*(Oss1x2^2 + Oss2x1^2) == As && 
       VU1x1*Oss1x1*(VU1x2*Oss1x2 + VU2x1*Oss2x1) == AUs &&
       -1 < VU1x1 < 1 && -1 < VU1x2 < 1 && -1 < VU2x1 < 1 &&
       -1 < Oss1x1 < 1 && -1 < Oss1x2 < 1 && -1 < Oss2x1 < 1,
      {VU1x1, VU1x2, VU2x1, Oss1x1, Oss1x2, Oss2x1},
      Reals]}],
  {AU, 0, 1/2, 1/20, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {As, 0, 2, 1/20, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {AUs, -1, 1, 1/20, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: manip]